# Dataframe is not recognizing the column?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe where I have different columns of prices of Reliance Stock. I can see that index of the dataframe is Date after I used `df.index`. However when I use `df["Date"]`, it gives me an error saying

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

```py
data = nsepy.get_history(symbol = "RELIANCE",start = datetime.date(2018,1,1) , end = datetime.datetime.now().date())
data["Date"]
```

Why I am not able to select the first column of this dataframe?

Comment: If its index then try using data.index. Index is not recognised as a column in pandas.

Comment: Try this to get index value as column data['date'] = data.index and then select you column . And let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Date" is the index of your dataframe and not a column.

Only the columns output by `df.columns` can be accessed using `df[<col_name>]`.

To check the index of your dataframe, just execute: `df.index`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"A": 10, "B": 5}, {"A":20, "B": 4}, {"A": 14, "B": 200}])
df = df.set_index('A')
print(df.index)
```

the output is:
`Int64Index([10, 20, 14], dtype='int64', name='A')`

To set a particular column of your dataframe to index:
`df = df.set_index(<col-name>)`

To undo the above (convert current index to a column):
`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

After resetting the index, you'll be able to access "Date" like a regular column, since it is no longer the index of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

[image]There is no column named Date in the Dataframe. The date you see is the index in the dataframe.
You can add Date column using following line:

data.reset_index(inplace = True)

Answer (score 0):

'Date' is index in this case. So you have to either  do data.index  or use reset_index like data.reset_index()['Date'].

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared details regarding your original dataframe.
Try printing your columns to see if 'Data' column exists

```
print(data.columns)
```

If you don't see 'Data' in the list, your dataframe does not contain this column, or it is the index column. In case its the latter, you can use

```
data.index
```